# Merge more than two lists in R

Tags: r, merge

Basically, I want to merge multiple lists in to a single list. All lists have same structure. Here is one example:

```
file1=list(A=1,B=2)
file2=list(A=2,B=3)
file3=list(A=3,B=4)
```

I know `mapply()` or `Map()` works.

```
> mapply(c, file1, file2, file3, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4
```

But the problem is that I actually have 500 lists, well, I can sure copy and paste object names 500 times. However, I'd like to learn how to do it efficiently. I have a vector containing names of each 500 lists, like this,

```
lsNames=c("file1","file2","file3")
```

but I have to no idea how to start, I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: You can also use `mget(ls(pattern='file\\d+'))`

Comment: Why are those 500 lists sitting in your workspace? They should be together in a list or environment from their creation.

Comment: @Roland each of them are results from a single simulation, I could actually run 500 simulation at once then I would have a single list which is what I want, but due to hardware limitation, I can only run one simulation then clean up some disk space, so I ended up with this bizarre situation

Comment: I still don't get it. If you run 500 simulations I sure hope you do so in a loop. But then I don't get how you can end up with 500 separate objects in your workspace instead of doing something like `res <- list();  for (i in seq_len(500) res[[i]] <- yourComputations` or (preferably) using `replicate`, `lapply` or `foreach`.

Comment: this would work if the simulation result is a vector or single values, but mine is a list, so the code you provided would produce a nested list which is actually 1 step closer to what I want but it's same as doing mget(), however that's still not what I need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an alternative that works by constructing and then evaluating the same call to `mapply()` shown in the OP:

```
do.call(mapply, c(FUN=c, sapply(lsNames, as.symbol), SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
# $A
# file1 file2 file3 
#     1     2     3 
# 
# $B
# file1 file2 file3 
#     2     3     4
```

Comment: elegant, there is an eval in do.call I guess?

Comment: I actually tried `as.symbol()` combined with `mapply()`, but never thought about using `do.call()` this way. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: If anyone cares,  `do.call(Map, c(f=c, sapply(lsNames, as.symbol)))` also work

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are after, but I have written a code that gets you from your lists to one data.frame.

```
library(plyr)

file1 = list(A = 1, B = 2)
file2 = list(A = 2, B = 3)
file3 = list(A = 3, B = 4)

lsNames = c("file1", "file2", "file3")

# defining new list
my_list <- list()

# getting data from your objects file_1...file_n to new list
for(lsName in seq_along(lsNames)){

  my_list[[lsName]] <- unlist(get(lsNames[lsName]))
}

# list to data.frame
my_df <- 
  ldply(my_list)

my_final_df <- 
  cbind(my_df, lsNames) 

# a look at result
my_final_df

  A B lsNames
1 1 2   file1
2 2 3   file2
3 3 4   file3
```

Comment: This would also do, what I need is to calculate the sd() and mean() of A and B, a data.frame do have the convenient format I need. Thanks a lot